# Change Text Strings On Specific WooCommerce Endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext

I'm trying to conditionally change strings on WooCommerce My Account Endpoints. Each time I try to add an endpoint condition it either breaks the site or doesn't work; however when I don't use the condition the string replace works. Maybe someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

**Working Snippet - Without Condition**

```
function change_endpoint_text( $translated ) {
        
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'List of coupons which are valid & available for use. Click on the coupon to use it. The coupon discount will be visible only when at least one product is present in the cart.', 'List of vouchers which are valid & available for use. Click on a voucher to use it. The discount will be visible only when at least one product is present in the cart.', $translated );

    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_endpoint_text' );
```

**Conditional Snippet Test - Not Working**

Note: I also tried using an is_account_page condition that seemed to break the site.

```
function change_endpoint_text( $translated ) {
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('wc-smart-coupons') ) {
        
        $translated = str_ireplace( 'List of coupons which are valid & available for use. Click on the coupon to use it. The coupon discount will be visible only when at least one product is present in the cart.', 'List of vouchers which are valid & available for use. Click on a voucher to use it. The discount will be visible only when at least one product is present in the cart.', $translated );

    }

    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_endpoint_text' );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, What exactly are you trying to check using `is_wc_endpoint_url`? Where does `wc-smart-coupons` come from? Are you using a third party plugin?

Comment: @Ruvee - I'm trying to check if I'm on a specific endpoint, and if I am then continue with the translation. In my example the endpoint `wc-smart-coupons` is coming from the WooCommerce Smart Coupons plugin but that's just for that one string. If I could successfully target a string on any endpoint then I'd be able to change messages in other areas too. Such as "The following addresses will be used on the checkout page by default" text on the `edit-adressess` endpoint an example. I'm not sure if I'm overcomplicating it or doing it entirely wrong honestly.

Comment: That's what i thought, you're using a third party plugin. Does this plugin register extra endpoints? I think `is_wc_endpoint_url` recognizes only the woocommerce default endpoints found in the woocommerce settings. Is `wc-smart-coupons` a separate page or is it just a `query variable`?

Comment: @Ruvee - Aaaah. I didn't realize that it would only recognize the default endpoints. It's a separate "page" much like how you'd see any of the other endpoints (i.e downloads, addresses, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for end points using `$wp->query_vars['custom_endpoint']`.

For example,

```
function change_endpoint_text ( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  global $wp;

  if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['wc-smart-coupons'] ) ) {

    if ($translated_text == 'some existing text') {
      $translated_text = __( 'The new replaced text', 'woocommerce');
    }

  }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_endpoint_text' );
```

Comment: The above snippet causes a 500 error but you and an Ruvee above definitely pointed out something that I didn't realize, that the `is_wc_endpoint_url` I'll keep tinkering. :)